# configure route to page that is in subfolder rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `design.html.erb` file in folder `views/services/`

How do I configure route to this page in `routes.rb`?
(I have a controller for static pages called static_pages_controller but I don't need any backend actions)
I need something like this:

```
  get '/services/design' => 'static_pages#what_to_write_here'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get '/services/design' => 'static_pages#design'
```

This would render the `design.html.erb` inside `views/static_pages/` directory.

In order to specify another view in another sub-folder you have to specify in your action:

```
def design
  render 'services/design'
end
```

This would render the `design.html.erb` inside `views/services/` directory.

Comment: So I knew this, but I was actually asking is there a way to tell rails what to render not in controller but in routes.rb.

Comment: @user2950593 Rails routes does mapping to controller and action. I don't think there would be a way to specify in routes which template to be rendered!

Answer (score 1):

get '/services/design', to: 'static_pages#design'
of course if you have method design in your static_pages_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem.